# How to implement tf.space_to_depth with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, linear-algebra

These is a function in `tensorflow` called [`tf.space_to_depth`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/space_to_depth). The implementation of this function in Tensorflow source code is so difficult for me. Could you please help me to implement it using `numpy`?

Here is some code to visualize how this function works. By the way, before everything, it is good to mention that the input to tensorflow's function should have input shape : `[batch, height, width, depth]`

Assuming this code. First we need to define a tensor:

```
norm = tf.reshape(tf.range(0,72),(1,6,6,2))
```

Here is the value of depth 1 (`norm[0,:,:,0]`):

```
[[ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10],
 [12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22],
 [24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34],
 [36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46],
 [48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58],
 [60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70]]
```

Here is the value of depth 2 (`norm[0,:,:,1]`):

```
[[ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11],
 [13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
 [25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35],
 [37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47],
 [49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59],
 [61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71]]
```

In the next step, I would like to apply `tf.space_to_depth` function and here it is:

```
trans = tf.space_to_depth(norm,2)
```

Output shape is : (1,3,3,8) and here is the output of this function:

```
trans[0,:,:,0]
[[ 0,  4,  8],
 [24, 28, 32],
 [48, 52, 56]]
trans[0,:,:,1]
[[ 1,  5,  9],
 [25, 29, 33],
 [49, 53, 57]]
trans[0,:,:,2]
[[ 2,  6, 10],
 [26, 30, 34],
 [50, 54, 58]]
trans[0,:,:,3]
[[ 3,  7, 11],
 [27, 31, 35],
 [51, 55, 59]]
trans[0,:,:,4]
[[12, 16, 20],
 [36, 40, 44],
 [60, 64, 68]]
trans[0,:,:,5]
[[13, 17, 21],
 [37, 41, 45],
 [61, 65, 69]]
trans[0,:,:,6]
[[14, 18, 22],
 [38, 42, 46],
 [62, 66, 70]]
trans[0,:,:,7]
[[15, 19, 23],
 [39, 43, 47],
 [63, 67, 71]]
```

May someone help me how can I implement a vectorized version of this function in numpy?

Appreciating in advance for any response!

Answer (score 4):

You can implement `space_to_depth` with appropriate calls to the `reshape()` and `swapaxes()` functions:

```
import numpy as np

def space_to_depth(x, block_size):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    batch, height, width, depth = x.shape
    reduced_height = height // block_size
    reduced_width = width // block_size
    y = x.reshape(batch, reduced_height, block_size,
                         reduced_width, block_size, depth)
    z = np.swapaxes(y, 2, 3).reshape(batch, reduced_height, reduced_width, -1)
    return z
```

Here are the examples from [the documentation of tf.space_to_depth](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/space_to_depth):

```
In [328]: x = [[[[1], [2]],
     ...:       [[3], [4]]]]
     ...: 

In [329]: space_to_depth(x, 2)
Out[329]: array([[[[1, 2, 3, 4]]]])

In [330]: x = [[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
     ...:       [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]]
     ...: 

In [331]: space_to_depth(x, 2)
Out[331]: array([[[[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]]]])

In [332]: x = [[[[1],   [2],  [5],  [6]],
     ...:       [[3],   [4],  [7],  [8]],
     ...:       [[9],  [10], [13],  [14]],
     ...:       [[11], [12], [15],  [16]]]]
     ...: 

In [333]: space_to_depth(x, 2)
Out[333]: 
array([[[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
         [ 5,  6,  7,  8]],

        [[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
         [13, 14, 15, 16]]]])
```

And here is your example:

```
In [334]: norm = np.arange(72).reshape(1, 6, 6, 2)

In [335]: trans = space_to_depth(norm, 2)

In [336]: trans[0, :, :, 0]
Out[336]: 
array([[ 0,  4,  8],
       [24, 28, 32],
       [48, 52, 56]])

In [337]: trans[0, :, :, 1]
Out[337]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [25, 29, 33],
       [49, 53, 57]])

In [338]: trans[0, :, :, 7]
Out[338]: 
array([[15, 19, 23],
       [39, 43, 47],
       [63, 67, 71]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am a little novice in numpy and having no idea about how to implement such a function.

Comment: Another thing which is so important for me is that if we change the input shape to [batch, depth, height, width], could you tell how can I change above code to get the exact similar result? @Warren Weckesser